# one sample t-test: result is 'infinity' - what do I report?

Tags: t-test

I have been comparing the outcomes from a number of groups to an expected value. The outcomes are a simple scale with three possible options: -1, 0, +1

The expected value is the '0' and one of my groups has answered with all '1's with the result that my t value is reading 'infinity'. Do I report this as infinity? Or is there an alternative?

I am also calculating effect sizes based upon the t-value which is obviously impossible in this case so what do I write instead?

thanks

Comment: You're doing one sample t-tests on data that can only take three values? Why would it have a t-distribution?

Comment: Can you say a bit more about the underlying question you're answering? What is this 'expected value', for example? And why is effect size based on the t-statistic? Wouldn't the effect be a difference in means?

Comment: Assume I understand nothing about stats - I'm doing a t-test because I've been told to do a t-test and I haven't the faintest idea why it would have a t-distribution nor what that even means.

The question is irrelevant but the possible answers have been dummy coded as -1, 0, +1 with the 0 as the expected outcome. I know absolutely nothing about effect sizes either but I have been told by higher powers (who have looked at my data) that I must provide effect sizes which this website suggested are calculated from the t-statistic and I've one t-statistic that has been calculated as infinity.

Comment: Sorry, had to edit my comment but took too long to do so so had to repost.

Comment: Which website and what effect size? It's a bit hard to educate third parties through intermediaries, especially when I don't even know what they actually said.

Comment: One good answer is not to do a t-test, but to use some other test that is suitable for these data.  Would this option be available to you?

Comment: @whuber, the OP is long gone. I don't think we'll ever get more information here.

Comment: @gung You never know.

Answer (score 1):

If your samples are not too small, then using one-sample t-tests is a reasonable advice as long as its null hypothesis "true mean is zero" is what you want to reject.

However, in the sample without any variation, you shouldn't run a t-test. The technical argument is very simple: To compute the corresponding test statistic, we need to divide by the sample standard deviation zero, which is "illegal".

To give an intuitive, non-technical reason, let's consider the following two settings:

1) The sample is small:

For small samples, the t-test requires the observations to be normal. This is not the case if all values are equal.

2) The sample is not too small:

For not too small samples, thanks to the Central Limit Theorem, the observations do not need to be normal in order to get reliable results from a t test. However it would be hard to believe that the observations were sampled independently if all values are equal. This is a major assumption of most univariate tests.

Comment: I think the problem yields to an informal argument. Statistical problems compare observed variability with some model, explicit or implicit as may be. If there is no variability, there is no statistical problem.

Comment: @Nick: Good point! I was thinking about a situation where samples are so small that estimated variability is zero simply by chance. But maybe I am thinking wrong.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your argument. If there is no observed variability, the standard formulas still make sense, but one has a limiting case. How and how far you explain that is open to choice. Conversely, my statement could be dismissed as rhetorical or wordplay, but depending on who is the audience it can be supplemented with the mathematics.